# Initializing child objects from parent

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I'm having a bit of a structural dilemma with designing my app. I want to use a series of nested loops to create a large amount of custom objects. Once those objects are created, I want to store them all into an object which is collection of those objects.

Visualized:

```
@interface CollectionOfObjectA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *reference;
@end
@implementation CollectionOfObjectA
-(CollectionOfObjectA *)init{
    NSMutableArray *ref = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i < largeNumber; i++){ // There will be nested loops.
        NSString *str = @"string made from each loop index";
        ObjA *obj = [[ObjA alloc] initWithIndexes: str]; 
        [ref addObject: obj];
    }
    self.reference = [ref copy];
}
@end

@interface ObjA : CollectionOfObjA
// several properties
@end
@implementation ObjA
-(ObjA *)initWithIndexes:(NSString *)indexes{
    self = [super init];
    // Use passed indexes to create several properties for this object.
    return self;
 }
 @end
```

What would be the best way about creating this object which is a collection of child objects? Am I incorrect in making ObjA a child of CollectionOfObjectA -- should it be the other way around? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a string to initialise these objects?  Isn't it better to use something that is easy to use?

Comment: I might use an NSArray of indexes rather than create a string. I'll need to iterate through the indexes to create the various properties for ObjA, so maybe NSArray would be easier. But that issue aside, how might I go about creating this collection?

Comment: I don't what's wrong with the approach you suggest yourself?

Comment: I suppose my main concern is that as the parent, CollectionOfObjA doesn't know what an ObjA is. So the line where I initialize a new ObjA file would require including ObjA's header in CollectionOfObjA's .m file. That just somehow seemed like an incorrect approach.

Comment: Including the `"ObjA.h"` is normal if you are creating new objects of `@class ObjA`, and cannot be avoided.  It's reasonable to expect the creator of an object to know *what* it is it's creating.

Comment: No, you don't need the header file at all to initialise an object. The header file is only ever used at compile time and it's only there to generate warnings about likely code mistakes. You can create ObjA without knowing anything about it except it's class name and the name of the initialiser method (both of which can come from an arbitrary string if you want).

Comment: When you say "largeNumber" what do you mean? A thousand? A hundred thousand? A hundred million?

Comment: stop, you really said, that "CollectionOfObjA" is a parent for "ObjA"? Logic, please

Comment: @trojanfoe I think that will likely be how I deal with this. Thank you. Abhi Beckert - Would that involve creating an id obj rather than ObjA object, since CollectionOfObjA doesn't know what it is? loldop -Your comment is pretty unhelpful, please elaborate.

Comment: @NateKimball please, tell us, why should class as "CollectionOfObjA" be a parent class for "ObjA"? So, "bank" is a parent class for "dollar"?

Comment: @loldop - If you'll read my initial post, that's the very question I'm asking for help on. If you would be kind enough to propose a solution, I'm sure me and other novice programmers like myself would be grateful.

Comment: @NateKimball yes, I've read you question. And you can read my answer as "advise". Many programmers have the same questions. So I suppose, that my answer with "canonical" style of architecture will be glad to see.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my advise: I have nearly ~30 custom objects. Like events. After that I make class `Factory` which can create all of them. And also this class `Factory` have method: `getAllObjects`.

Like this:

```
#include "CustomEvent.h"
@interface EventFactory

+(NSArray*)allEvents;

@end

@implementation EventFactory

-(CustomEvent*)firstEvent{/*something here*/}
-(CustomEvent*)secondEvent{/*yes, you should init custom object here*/}
-(CustomEvent*)thirdEvent{/*and after that you can put them*/}
/*
...
*/
+(NSArray*)allEvents{
      EventFactory* factory = [[EventFactory alloc]init];
      return @[
               [factory firstEvent],
               [factory secondEvent],
               /*...*/
               [factory lastEvent]
               ];

}
@end
```

Here I return `NSArray` because I don't need, actually, know anything of them. They already have handlers and they subscribed on custom notifications. You can return `NSDictionary` for better access.

P.S: for better explanation you can read article in wiki about [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

But, if you want better manipulation of objects, you should use other pattern:[Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

What I mean?

```
@interface EventCollection{
   NSMutableArray* YourArray;
}

-(void)addCustomEvent:(CustomEvent*)event atPosition:(NSInteger)position;
-(void)removeCustomEventAtPosition:(NSInteger)position;
-(void)seeAllEvents;
-(void)seeAllPositions; /*if you want*/
-(void)doesThisPositionAvailable:(NSInteger)position;

@end

@implementation EventCollection

-(void)addCustomEvent:(CustomEvent*)event atPosition:(NSInteger)position{
   /*maybe you should check if this position available*/
   if ([self doesThisPositionAvailable:position]){
        /*add element and save position*/
   }
}

-(void)removeCustomEventAtPosition:(NSInteger)position{
    if (![self doesThisPositionAvailable:position]){
          /*destroy element here*/
    }
}

-(void)seeAllEvents{
    /*yes, this method is the main method, you must store somewhere your objects.
      you can use everything, what you want, but don't share your realization.
      maybe, you want use array, so, put it as hidden variable. and init at the initialization of your collection
    */
    for (CustomEvent* event in YourArray){
         [event description];
    }
}

@end
```